# Bartle Elements of Integration Exercise 7W

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I have solved problem $7W$ in a particular case when $\varphi$ is **uniformly continuous** and I wonder if there are any counterexamples when uniform continuity isn't satisfied.

> **7.W.** If $f_n$ converges to $f$ in $L^p$ on an arbitrary measure space and $\varphi$ is continuous and satisfies $|\varphi(t)|\leq K|t|$ for all $t\in \mathbb{R}$, then $\varphi \circ f_n$ converges to $\varphi \circ f$ in $L^p$. Conversely if $\varphi$ does not satify $|\varphi(t)|\leq K|t|$, there exists a measure space and a sequence $f_n$ which converges in $L^p$ to $f$, but such that $\varphi\circ f_n$ does not converge in $L^p$ to $\varphi\circ f$.

---

Before you read my answer below, I wanted to share a little bit of theory which is needed, but you may skip these because they are fairly well known:

**1. Convergence in $L^p$ implies convergence in measure.**

> $$0\xleftarrow[]{n}\int|f_n-f|^pd\mu \geq \int_{\{x: |f(x)-f_{n}(x)|\geq \alpha\}}|f_n-f|^pd\mu\geq \alpha^p \mu(\{x:\:\: |f(x)-f_n(x)|\geq \alpha\})\geq 0$$

**2. Convergence in measure implies there is a subsequence that converges pointwise almost everywhere and almost uniformly.**

> We define a subsequence such that $E_k=\{x: \:|f_{n_k}(x)-f(x)|\geq 1/2^k\}$ such that $\mu(E_k)<1/2^k$. Clearly if $n\geq n_o (\epsilon)$: $$\mu(\limsup E_k)=\mu(\cap_{n=1}^\infty \cup_{n=k}^\infty E_k)\leq \mu(\cup_{n=n_o}^\infty E_k)\leq \sum_{n=n_o}^\infty \frac{1}{2^n}<\epsilon$$ Hence, $\mu(\limsup E_k)=0$. If $x\in (\limsup E_k)^C=\cup_{n=1}^\infty \cap_{k=n}^\infty E_k^C\Rightarrow x\in \cap_{n_o}^\infty E_k^C$ for some $n_o$ $\Rightarrow |f(x)-f_{n_{k}}(x)|<1/2^k$ for all $k\geq n_o$ so, there is pointwise convergence almost everywhere. If we take $n_o$ sufficciently large $E_\delta =\cup_{n=n_o}^\infty E_k$ is such that $\mu(E_\delta)<\delta$. In $E_\delta^C$ it is easy to see $f_{n_k}$ converges uniformly to $f$.

**3. Almost uniform convergence implies convergence in measure.**

> Let $E_\varepsilon$ be such that $\mu(E_\varepsilon)<\varepsilon$ and $f_n$ converges almost uniformly in $E_\varepsilon^C$. In this case, if $n\geq n_o(\epsilon)$, we have $|f_n(x)-f(x)|<\varepsilon$ for all $x\in E_\varepsilon^C$ and so $\{ x:\: |f_n(x)-f(x)|\geq \alpha\}\subset E_\varepsilon$ and $\mu(\{ x: \: |f_n(x)-f(x)|\geq \alpha \})<\varepsilon$.

---

We finally prove Bartles **7W** but we ask $\varphi$ to be uniformly continous.

$(\Rightarrow)$ We have $f_n\xrightarrow[]{L^p} f$ so $f_n\xrightarrow[]{\mathcal{M}} f$. But this implies there is a subsequence such that $f_{n_k}\xrightarrow[]{} f$ pointwise almost everywhere and also almost uniformly. Because $\varphi$ is continuous, we have $\varphi\circ f_{n_k}\xrightarrow[]{} \varphi \circ f$ pointwise almost everywhere and because $\varphi$ is uniformly continuous we have $\varphi\circ f_{n_k}\xrightarrow[]{} \varphi \circ f$ also almost uniformly.

We prove $\varphi\circ f_{n_k}\xrightarrow[]{L^p} \varphi \circ f$ using Vitali's Theorem:

**1.1.** $\varphi\circ f_{n_k}\xrightarrow[]{\mathcal{M}} \varphi \circ f$

This follows from the fact almost uniform convergence implies convergence in measure.

**1.2.** $\exists \delta(\varepsilon)>0$ such that if $\mu(E)<\delta$, $\int |\varphi\circ f_{n_k}|d\mu<\varepsilon^p$ for all $k\in \mathbb{N}$.

This follows from the fact $f_n$ satisfies a similar property property with $\varepsilon'=\epsilon/K$:

$$\int_E|\varphi\circ f_{n_k}|^pd\mu\leq K^p \int_E|f_{n_k}|^p d\mu <K^p\epsilon'^p=\epsilon^p$$

**1.3.**  $\exists E_\varepsilon$ such that $\mu(E_\varepsilon)<\infty$ and $\int_{E_\varepsilon^C} |\varphi \circ f_{n_k} |^p d\mu<\epsilon^p$ for all $k\in \mathbb{N}$

This follows from the fact $f_n$ satisfies this property with $\varepsilon'=\epsilon/K$:

$$\int_{E_\varepsilon^C}|\varphi\circ f_{n_k}|^pd\mu\leq K^p \int_{E_\varepsilon^C}|f_{n_k}|^p d\mu <K^p\epsilon'^p=\epsilon^p$$

This finishes the proof that $\varphi \circ f_{n_k}$ converges to $\varphi \circ f$ in $L_p$.
If $\varphi \circ f_n $ didn’t converge to $\varphi \circ f$ in $L^p$, we could extract a subsequence which wouldn’t take any subsequence convergent to $\varphi \circ f$ in contradiction to what we proved.

$(\Leftarrow)$ For every natural number there $\exists t_n$ such that $\varphi(t_n)> n|t_n|$.

**Case I:** $t_n\not=0 \: ,\:\forall n$. We take $\mathbb{N}$ with the partition sigma algebra and also discrete measure $\mu(E)=\sum_{n\in E} \frac{1}{|t_n|^p n^2}$. Let $f(n)=|t_n|$. It is easilly seen that:

$$\int|\varphi \circ f|^pd\mu=\sum_n|\varphi\circ f(n)|^p\mu(n)\geq\sum_n n^p|t_n|^p \mu(n)\geq \sum_n\frac{1}{n}=\infty $$
$$\int |f|^pd\mu=\sum_n|t_n|^p\mu(n)=\sum_n\frac{1}{n^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}<\infty$$

**Case II:** $\exists t_n$ such that $t_n=0$. We take $\mathbb{N}$ with the partition sigma algebra and also the counting measure. $|\varphi(0)|>0$. We take $f\equiv 0$.

$$\int|\varphi\circ f|^p d\mu=\sum_n |\varphi(0)|^p=\infty$$
$$\int|f|^p d\mu =0 <\infty$$

In both cases, we define $f_n=(1-1/n)f$. Clearly they are dominated by $|f|$ which is in $L_p$, and so, by the dominated convergence theorem $f_n \xrightarrow[]{L_p} f$. However, $\varphi \circ f_n$ cannot converge to $\varphi \circ f$ because this last function is not in $L^p$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We do not need uniform continuity! My teacher cleverly used Egoroff today in class to adapt the proof when $\varphi$ is only continuous.

($\Rightarrow $) If $f_n\xrightarrow{L^p} f_{}$, then $f_n\xrightarrow{\mathcal{M}} f_{}$ and there is a subsequence $(f_{n_k})$ that converges almost everywhere to  $f$. Because $f_{n_k}\xrightarrow{L^p} f$, we have using Vitali that there exists $E_\epsilon$ such that $\mu(E_\epsilon)< \infty$ and $\int_{E_\varepsilon^C} |f_{n_k}|^p<\varepsilon^p$.

Claim: If we restrict our space to $X'=E_\epsilon$, we have $\phi \circ f_{n_k}|_{E_{\epsilon}}\xrightarrow{L^p} \phi \circ f|_{E_\epsilon}$.

This follows from Vitali:

Because of continuity, $\varphi \circ f_{n_k}\rightarrow \varphi \circ f$ almost everywhere in $X$, in particular in $X'$.

**1.1.** $\varphi\circ f_{n_k}\xrightarrow[]{\mathcal{M}} \varphi \circ f$

This follows from Egoroff! We have pointwise convergence in $X'=E_\epsilon$ and $\mu(X')<\infty$.

**1.2.** $\exists \delta(\varepsilon)>0$ such that if $\mu(E)<\delta$ where $E\subset E_\epsilon$, $\int |\varphi\circ f_{n_k}|d\mu<\varepsilon^p$ for all $k\in \mathbb{N}$.

This follows from the fact $f_n$ satisfies a similar property property with $\varepsilon'=\epsilon/K$:

$$\int_E|\varphi\circ f_{n_k}|^pd\mu\leq K^p \int_E|f_{n_k}|^p d\mu <K^p\epsilon'^p=\epsilon^p$$

**1.3.**  $\exists E_\varepsilon=X'$ such that $\mu(E_\varepsilon)<\infty$ and $\int_{X'\setminus E_\varepsilon} |\varphi \circ f_{n_k} |^p d\mu=0<\epsilon^p$ for all $k\in \mathbb{N}$

This proves $\varphi\circ f_{n_k}|_{E_\varepsilon}\xrightarrow{L^p} \varphi\circ f|_{E_\varepsilon}$
Therefore we have that for $k\geq k_o$ certainly $||(\varphi\circ f_{n_k}-\varphi \circ f)\chi_{E_\varepsilon}||_{L^p}<\epsilon$. Finaly:

$$||(\varphi\circ f_{n_k}-\varphi \circ f)||_{L^p}\leq ||(\varphi\circ f_{n_k}-\varphi \circ f)\chi_{E_{\varepsilon}} ||_{L^p}+||(\varphi\circ f_{n_k}\chi_{E_\varepsilon^C}||+||\varphi \circ f\chi_{E_{\varepsilon}^C} ||_{L^p}$$

However, because of the way we defined $E_{\varepsilon}^C$ we have $||\varphi \circ f_{n_k}\chi_{E_{\varepsilon}^C} ||_{L_p}<\varepsilon$ Also, by Fatou's Lemma and pointwise convergence of our sequence almost everywhere:

$$||\varphi \circ f\chi_{E_{\varepsilon}^C} ||_{L^p}=||\liminf\varphi \circ f_{n_k}\chi_{E_{\varepsilon}^C}||\leq \left(\liminf \int \varphi \circ f_{n_k}\chi_{E_{\varepsilon}^C} d\mu\right)^{1/p}\leq (\epsilon^p)^{1/p}=\epsilon$$

Therefore, we finally have:

$$||(\varphi\circ f_{n_k}-\varphi \circ f)||_{L^p}< 3\epsilon$$

Because $\epsilon$ was arbitrarily chosen, we need $\varphi\circ f_{n_k}\xrightarrow{L^p}\varphi \circ f$.

$(\Leftarrow)$ This remains unchanged from what I originally wrote.

Answer (score 0):

Uniform continuity isn't needed. I recently came upon a solution by [geetha290krm](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4809816/1015934) which solves this problem in a much more elementary way! But it depends on having a cleverer idea. I think it is more intructive to first start with Vitali because it involves less tricks, so read the other answer I wrote to this first.

---

**Fact 1:** Minkowski can be extended to infinite sums!

This follows from Fatou and regular Minkowski:
$$\left|\left|\sum_{j=1}^\infty g_n \right|\right|^p_p=\int\liminf\left|\sum_{j=1}^ng_n\right|^pd\mu\leq\liminf\int\left|\sum_{j=1}^n g_n\right|^pd\mu\leq$$
$$\liminf \left(\sum_{j=1}^n\left(\int |g_n|^p d\mu\right)^{\frac{1}{p}}\right)^p=\left(\sum_{j=1}^\infty||g_n||_p\right)^p$$

**Fact 2:** If $f_n \xrightarrow{L^p} f$ there exists a subsequence $f_{n_j}$ converging pointwise to $f$ almost everywhere and such that $|f_{n_j}|\leq g$ where $g$ is in $L^p$.

Because $f_{n}\xrightarrow{\mathcal{M}} f$, we may extract a subsequence converging pointwise to $f$, say $f_{n_j}$. From this we extract another subsequence with $||f_{n_{j_k}}-f||_p< 1/2^k $. We take $g:=\sum_{k=1}^\infty|f_{n_{j_k}}-f|+|f|$. Clearly:

$$|f_{n_{j_k}}|\leq |f_{n_{j_k}}-f|+|f|\leq \sum_{k=1}^\infty|f_{n_{j_k}}-f|+|f|=g$$

Furthermore, because of **Fact 1** we have:

$$||g||_p\leq \sum_{k=1}^\infty||f_{n_{j_k}}-f||_p+||f||_p<1+||f||_p<\infty$$

---

Finally we prove our result. For every sequence $f_{n}$ coverging in $L^p$ to $f$, we take $f_{n_j}$ as in **Fact 2**. By continuity $\varphi \circ f_{n_j}\rightarrow \varphi \circ f$. Furthermore, $|\varphi \circ f_{n_j}(x)|\leq K |f_{n_j}(x)|\leq Kg$ but $g\in L^p$. Clearly $\varphi \circ f_{n_{j}}-\varphi \circ f\rightarrow 0$ and is bounded by $K(g+|f|)$ which is in $L^p$ so by Lebesgue's dominated convergence theorem:

$$\int|\varphi \circ f_{n_j}-\varphi \circ f|^p=||\varphi\circ f_{n_j}-\varphi\circ f||_p^p\xrightarrow{j\rightarrow \infty} 0$$

If we had $\varphi \circ f_{n}\not\rightarrow \varphi \circ f$ in $L^p$ we could construct a subsequence which stays a safe distance from $\varphi \circ f$. But that would contradict our finding of $f_{n_{j_k}}$ which converges to $f$ in $L^p$!