# $f_n\xrightarrow[]{L^p}f\Rightarrow |f_{n_j}|\leq g$

Tags: measure-theory

[image]

Part (b) is just Lebesgue's Dominated Convergence Theorem which can be applied due to part (a). Suppose it didn't converge, we could extract a subsequence which would always remain distant from $\int \varphi(f) d\mu$, but this is absurd because from part (a) we might extract a bounded subsequence which would converges to $\int \varphi(f) d\mu$ by LDCT!

For part (a), I am having quite a bit of trouble. Even if we have some sort of uniform convergence (which we probably don’t) $|f_{k_{n_j}}|\leq\epsilon+|f|$ for $j\geq j_o$ is useless if our measure space is not finite. Also I am not sure where Radon measures take place... Radon is nice if we want to have freedom in calculating the measure of borel sets, but there is no immediate borel set unless we resort to simple functions but that would be a mess.

Comment: Show us what you've done before

Comment: As I said, I have only done part (b). Convergence in $L_p$ implies there is a subsequence that converges pointwise. By continuity $\varphi\circ  f_{n_j}$ converges pointwise and we aply LDCT due to part (a). But I really have no clue about part (a).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $h=\sum |f_{k_n}-f|$. Note that $\|h\|_p\leq \sum \|f_{k_n}-f\|_p\leq \sum \frac 1 {2^{n}}<\infty$, so $h \in L^{p}$. Also, $|f_{k_n}|\leq h+|f|$. Take $g=|f|+h$.